Firewall de Windows | Problemas de bloqueo
tengo un problema algo extraño en windows server, basicamente estoy aumentando el nivel de seguridad, por ejemplo el ping lo inhabilite y efectivamente cuando se hace ping ip indica tiempo excedido como se espera, pero revisando a fondo contra ataques de ddos y ejecutando este comando
ping -s 8192  -i 0.001 IP_DESTINO   noto que el trafico de red se ve afectado aun cuando ya esta bloqueado, adicionalmente he bloqueado la ip desde donde se ejecuta ese comando de prueba y aun asi se ve afectado, no entiendo que ocurre ya que se supone que esta bloqueado ese protocolo, entonces por que lo afecta ?
si alguien tiene alguna idea o sabe como corregirlo le agradezco

La respuesta puede versar más en la parte del firewall de tu red que en el de Windows ya que este ultimo en realidad es muy limitado, cabe mencionar que el fortinet por ejemplo ya tiene soluciones para este tipo de ataque, ya sea desde la red interna como la web, espero soluciones tu problema.
